# Copy a set of files into specific directories based on filename

Tags: windows, filenames

How can I copy series of files located in one folder into a specified folder based on the each file name in Windows?

For example the files:

**ProviderA.pdf** copied to folder->   \ProviderA\report\

**ProviderB.pdf** copied to folder->   \ProviderB\report\

**ProviderC.pdf** copied to folder->   \ProviderC\report\

I would like to traverse the list of files and from the file name (minus the extension) be able to copy each file to the folder specified by the file name.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /b *.pdf >foo
for /f "tokens=1 delims=. " %i in (foo) do copy %i.pdf %i\report
del foo
```

If the directories don't already exist, substitute this command:

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=. " %i in (foo) do md %i\report&copy %i.pdf %i\report
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Gregory.  It looks like this creates the directories but not copy the files.  When I replaced copy for md I got: i\report was unexpected at this time.  What am I missing?  Thanks.

Comment: Oops, sorry.  I've edited the answer to give the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to loop through files in current folder, create a folder using the filename (without the extension) if it doesn't already exist, then copy file into the new folder.

```
for %%G in (*.pdf) do (
    if not exist %%~nG md %%~nG
    copy %%G %%~nG
)
```